# Scala - extract Either type parameters

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-systems

Is it possible to extract type parameters in Scala like this:

```
def some[T <: Either[A, B]](implicit ta: TypeTag[A], tb: TypeTag[B]): T = {
  // A =:= String
  // B =:= Int
  // ...
}

some[Either[String, Int]]()
```

?

Comment: Why can't you use a method `def some[A, B](implicit ta: TypeTag[A], tb: TypeTag[B]): Either[A, B]`?

Comment: @senia because in original this is implicit definition for spray directive: implicit def someD[T <: Either[A, B]] = new FSOD[T] { // ... }

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Why you can't use `implicit def someD[A, B] = new FSOD[Either[A, B]] { // ... }`?

Comment: @senia You're right, I can just use `some[A, B]`. Thanks!

Comment: Note that in some cases it could be important to specify the result type of implicit method explicitly like this: `implicit def someD[A, B]: FSOD[Either[A, B]] = new FSOD[Either[A, B]] { // ... }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could rewrite your method like this:

```
def some[A, B](implicit ta: TypeTag[A], tb: TypeTag[B]): Either[A, B] = ???
```